# Multiline Documentation in robot framework

Tags: automated-tests, functional-testing, restructuredtext, robotframework

I want to document test scenarios, the principle behind the scenarios etc. in robot test case itself. For that the documentation need to support multiline features and formatting. Is there anyway to include documents in some formats like `rst` such that I will have more formatting power with easy syntax.

Answer (score 11):

You can spread documentation across multiple lines, and robot supports some simple markup. For information about the specific markup it supports, see [Documentation formatting](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting) in the [robotframework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).

My team uses the pipe-delimited format, and we spread documentation out like this:

```
| Test Case 1
| | [Documentation]
| | ... | = Example Heading =
| | ... | *bold* _italic_ 
| | ... | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
| | ... | do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore sed magna
| | ... | aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
| | ... | ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Comment: You can also have multiple `[Documentation]` lines, which automatically append to previous.

Comment: @MarkHu since robot >=2.9 this is deprecated 
`Invalid syntax in test case 'My test': Setting '[Documentation]' used multiple times.`

Answer (score 0):

The [Robot Framework user guide](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#documentation-formatting) goes through the different ways of writing documentation. There is also the [testdoc-tool](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#test-data-documentation-tool-testdoc) for generating high level documentation based on test cases.